# How to fill the array values with the key values?

Tags: php

I have a form with 2 elements:

- checkboxes to select roles among a list
- a radio button to reverse the conditions

Depending if the radio button is opt-in, I am getting the roles array, that will be used to generate some sql:

```php
$user_roles = array_filter($config->get('purge_users_roles')); 
if($config->get('reverse_role_purge_condition') == 1){
    $user_roles = array_filter($config->get('purge_users_roles'), function($x) {
        return $x === 0;
    });
    foreach ($user_roles as $key => $value){
        $user_roles[$key]=$key;
        var_dump($user_roles);     
    } 
}
```

I'm using `var_dump` to display the unselected values:

> array (size=2)   'membre_du_site' => int 0   'admin_site' => int 0

when in the other case, that would be somthg like :

> array (size=2) 'membre_du_site' => 'membre_du_site' 'admin_site' =>
>   'admin_site'

What is the best way to fill all array values with the corresponding key values, to get the same array structure in both cases?

Comment: You already have values, what's the purpose of duplicating?

Comment: The values are used for generating an sql request.I am adding a possibility to reverse conditions, the $user_arrays is not the values selected from the form but all the others:   $user_roles = array_filter($config->get('purge_users_roles'));
  if($config->get('reverse_role_purge_condition') == 1){
    $user_roles = array_filter($config->get('purge_users_roles'), function($x) { return  $x === 0; });
    foreach ($user_roles as $key => $value){
      $user_roles[$key]=$key;
    }
  }

Comment: Please, [edit] your question, this code is not readable.

Comment: i understand u are curious about the purpose but the question remain thant one described independantely.

Comment: finding an alternative would be another unrelated question.

Comment: Sorry, I don;t understand the purpose of all these.

Comment: i have edited it then

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? What's your expected and actual outcome?